# Transform log4net Appender Connection String Using Octopus Deploy

Tags: asp.net, log4net, octopus-deploy

I have a number of named appenders configured in my `web.config` files and I'm wondering if it is possible to address these as normal Variable transforms as part of a standard deployment?

What I want to be able to change is the value of the `connectionString`

The XML looks like this:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender_DNOA" 
       type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <immediateFlush value="true" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, 
           System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, 
           Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString 
            value="data source=MyServer;initial catalog=DNOALog_Dev;
            integrated security=false;persist security info=True;
         User ID=UserId;Password=pwd" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [Octopus Deploy documentation](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files), probably not.

However, log4net since 1.2.11 has had the ability to reference a ConnectionString by name from the `connectionStrings` section of the web.config file:

```
<connectionStringName value="ConnStringName" />
```

You could then keep your log4net connection string in the connectionStrings section, reference it by name in your log config, and use Octopus to transform the connection string as in their documentation.

(Just to note, if you're using an earlier version of log4net then upgrading may be an issue if you have other components which depend on the older version, as [the signing key changed in 1.2.11 as well](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#two-snks))

Comment: Hey thanks for doing the leg work here, that's a great solution, +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Octopus 2.3 leveraging the new Variable substitution feature. Using this your code would look something like this:

```
<connectionStringName value="#{ConnStringName}" />
```

In your release you would pass in a variable based on environment machine or whatever feels good and that should get you want you want.

Take a look at the blog post for more information. [Variable Substitution](https://octopusdeploy.com/blog/variable-substition-in-files)